# deleting doucments after file upload

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I need to submit the application and upload the file for the application.
I can upload the files only after the successful application submission. I'm doing this by having the upload method inside the success callback of the application submission.

but i have navigate away from the application submission page once the application is submitted successfully but upload will be happening in background.

The case is fine till now.

But i need to delete the documents once the upload is successful. As upload is happening in background, any success callback inside the upload method is not happening.

Is there any logic to delete the documents even after we navigate away from current state?

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigating after the success response of your application submission, there is no way to delete the uploaded files/documents from there itself. You need something else to do so, or you need to stop the navigation to do so.

Still if navigation is mandatory, what we can do is, you need a detail-page or so for the application submitted, where you can list the uploaded files/documents whose records would be available in database you stored after you got the success response of application submission.

As we are listing the files/documents from the database, we will be having a unique id(primary key) for every file/document uploaded, using which you can perform the deletion of any file/document uploaded.

Comment: Yeah i had this idea too. What if the user doesn't visit the detail page or status page of application too often.

Comment: That might be the case, but if they want to delete their uploaded document, they have to visit to the detail page. Might be no other solution available, if you are navigating.